# How to make Gimp brush size pressure sensitive?

Tags: gimp, drawing-tablet

I've just downloaded Gimp and am trying to figure out how to change the brush dynamics so that the brush thickness changes relative to the pressure I apply to the stylus.  There seems to be a way to do this by using 'Basic Simple' dynamics, but I am unable to change any of the settings listed here.  I read another post saying that I could have to duplicate the brush to be able to change those settings, but I cannot figure out any way to do that.

How can I make the width of my brush pressure sensitive?

Answer (score 2):

"Assets" that come with Gimp (brushes, gradients, patterns... and brush dynamics) and not editable by users (because they are assumed to be shared between users).

If you need to edit brush dynamics, you have to create them in your user assets, either by creating a new one from scratch in the Dynamics editor, or by copying an existing one (the copy will implicitly go in your own user assets). Use the Dynamics list dialog for this (*Windows>Dockable dialogs>Paint Dynamics*).

But the Dynamics you want already exists as `Pressure size`.

**Note:** when you start using Gimp with a tablet, the first thing to do is to open *Windows>Dockable dialog>Device status*. If this only lists a single device (likely "Core pointer") then your tablet isn't seen like a tablet and you won't get pressure sensitivity.

Comment: OK so how do I MAKE it be seen as a tablet?

Comment: Depends on OS, and tablet... Wacom/Intuos/Bamboo and Huion usually work. Tablet has to be plugged in before Gimp is started. On Linux it works without doing anything special.When I was on Windows (a long time ago, so XP) I had to run the Wacom config utility at least once, this made it write a config file somewhere that the Gimp table support could find/read. You know your tablet is seen as a tablet if `Windows > Dockable dialog > Device status` shows more than one device (`Core pointer` lumps together the non-pressure pointers: mouse, trackpad, trackpoint...).